# Timeseries forecasting repeadted results

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, forecasting

I'm trying to fit GBR on a timeseries of profit of a company. The code looks like this:

```
df1=pd.ExcelFile('data_share.xlsx')
df_all=df1.parse("Sheet1")
df_all.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
df_all = df_all.set_index(['JCCreateDate'])
df_all = df_all.resample('M').sum()
df_all = df_all[:-1]

nrm = np.linalg.norm(df_all.values)
data = df_all.values
data /= nrm
temp = np.array([])

for i in range(data.shape[0]-16):
    temp = np.append(temp,data[i:(i+16)])
np_data = temp.reshape((-1,16))
# np.random.shuffle(np_data)

np_data_new = np_data[:-4,:]

X = np_data_new[:,:-1]
y = np_data_new[:,-1]

evl = np_data[-4:,:-1]

# #############################################################################
# Fit regression model for testing

params = {'learning_rate':0.1, 'n_estimators':150, 'max_depth':1, 'min_samples_split':30, 'min_samples_leaf': 1}
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
clf.fit(X, y)
o = clf.predict(evl)

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

print("MAPE = ",mean_absolute_percentage_error(np_data_new[-4:,-1], o), "%")
#Forecasting the output
x = df_all[-15:].values.reshape(1,-1)
o = clf.predict(x)
output = np.append(output, o)
for i in range(12):
  x = np.append(x, o)
  x = x[1:]
  o = clf.predict(x.reshape(1,-1))
  output = np.append(output, o)
```

The MAPE I'm getting on test set (`evl`) is around 23%. But when I try to do the forecasting outside the dataset I'm getting repeated results like this:

```
> output*nrm
array([19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737,
       19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737,
       19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737,
       19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737, 19334923.35894737,
       19334923.35894737, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666,
       18326427.63866666, 18326427.63866666])
```

Comment: If your time series data is univariate? It's hard to tell from your code.

Comment: @SkanderH. It's univariate. Are hyperparameters responsibles for this ?